# Moving Magento from server to server - Archive files too large

Tags: magento-1.7

As my e-stores are too big to zip and download everything, I want to know what folders I should download from the old server and move to the new Magento installation, in order to get it quickly up and running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking the only thing that gets really large on Magento is the media folder. The rest you can transfer easily by creating either a ZIP or TAR on the server.

In case you have access to SSH you can use the following command to create a TAR excluding the `media` and `var` directory.

```
tar -czf ./backup.tar --exclude=./media --exclude=./var ./
```

But if you're moving the database (with products etc) also you'll need the `media` directory as well as it contains the product images.

To transfer everything from one server to the other you can use the following if you have SSH access on both servers

```
scp -r -p /path/to/current/installation [user]@[serveraddress]:/path/to/destination
```

Comment: There is one dynamic bash script for backup magento db + files with many options, you may try that. FYI, I am using this script for almost every Magento project to take regular backups: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/backup-magento-project-files-db-using-bash-script/

Comment: nice! I'll give that a try

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use rsync to do transfers

```
rsync -avz -e ssh /path/to/local/ user@removeserver.com:/path/to/new/
```

I would also exclude if you don't want to copy all the extra cache files.

You can hit this command more than once and it will only copy new items the second time!

The last thing is to move the DB: I normally do a dump and restore then update your core_config_data table

Comment: Are there any more advantages to using rsync over scp? Anyway, I already like it better then scp :) +1

Comment: Once you've discovered rsync, you don't ever want to go back.

Comment: You can add excludes and exclude lists in rsync

Comment: @brentwpeterson never worked with ssh, but what is path/to/new? is it webserver public_html?

Comment: Basically you have rsync -avz -e ssh from/ to/
http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/rsync.1.php

Comment: Another advantage is the --progress switch, which ads a nice progress bar. With scp you just don't know when it will be finished.